# Facebook publish with app key : rate limit

Tags: facebook-graph-api, quota

I use Graph API to publish on facebook walls without token (only App key) 
What is the quota ?

I need to be able to publish some posts on thousand differents users in some minutes.

Thanks

Comment: there are no static limits, facebook does not really publish their limits, afaik they are dynamic anyway, depending on several factors (the number of active app users, for example).

Comment: what exactly do you want to post on thousands of different user walls anyway?

Comment: and why would you post that on thousands of different user walls? keep in mind that EVERY single post should be authorized by the user. i am 100% sure your app will not get approval for publish_actions.

Comment: possibly thousands, because during the event there might be thousands of users

Comment: No such thing "publish with app key". The correct one is "publish opengraph action with App Access Token" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/wordpress/open-graph-action). Most importantly, ensure your usage of API didn't violate TOS of this platform.(https://developers.facebook.com/policy#opengraph)

Comment: What we call the app access token is in fact the app id + app secret but well. About policy usage, it is, but thanks for your reminder.